# Flatten array of iterators

Tags: php, iterator, spl

I tried different combinations of SPL Iterators, but I can't find a way to implement recursive iteration over array of iterators. Here is analog of what I'm looking for but implemented using Generators:

```
private function recursiveIterator(): iterable
{
    $iterators = [
        $this->firstIterator(),
        $this->secondIterator(),
    ];

    foreach ($iterators as $iterator) {
        yield from $iterator;
    }
}
```

Is there any way to write the analog of the above code using SPL Iterators?

Thanks in advance!

P.S. Basically the code flattens array of values

```
[[1, 2], [10, 20]]
```

to

```
[1, 2, 10, 20]
```

Comment: If you have more than one iterator, and you want to iterate over each one in sequence then the tool for the job is [`AppendIterator`](http://php.net/appenditerator).  If you have a nested array, and want to walk over all values then [`RecursiveArrayIterator`](http://php.net/recursivearrayiterator) in conjunction with [`RecursiveIteratorIterator`](http://php.net/recursiveiteratoriterator) is a good place to look. Good luck.

Comment: `iterator_to_array(new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($array)), false);`

Comment: @Kazz it doesn't work

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c5856ca7aac7aa3b32fdf98518de8d7ed161ce19

Comment: @salathe It looks like 'AppendIterator' is what I were looking for, thanks! Unfortunately it has strange implementation, I can't call `$iter = new AppendIterator(); array_walk($iterators, [$iter, 'append']);`

Comment: @Kazz here is correct example and it doesn't work http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/abf917aeee11c94655fd50be78129ee27fc240d3

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6c36807bd40f7522133b1946015a63309765d1d3

Comment: @glagola `array_walk()` passes two arguments to the callback function (the value and key), which `AppendIterator::append()` does not expect. Ordinarily, built-in PHP functions and methods would issue an E_WARNING message (e.g. "Warning: AppendIterator::append() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given in..."), however `ArrayIterator::append()` decides to not follow convention and instead silently exits the method early without a warning and without appending the iterator.  If you used `array_map()` or a plain-old `foreach` to append the iterators, those would work fine.

Comment: @salathe Thanks, `array_map([$iter = new \AppendIterator(), 'append'], $iterators);` works perfectly.